# Dateformatter returns different dates

Tags: ios, swift

Please check the code bellow:

```
func testDate() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateEnd = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 15, to: Date())

        let df:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm"
        df.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
        df.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone

        let startDateLabel = df.string(from: dateEnd!)
        print(startDateLabel)

        let min = df.date(from: startDateLabel)!
        print(min)
    }
```

**Output**

print1: March 12, 2020 14:48

print2: 2019-12-22 09:48:00 +0000

Comment: what you want in output ?

Comment: `YYYY` is wrong. See the duplicate.

Comment: I want the same date string as a date object

Comment: use - `df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"`

Comment: @vadian please elaborate

Comment: Please read the duplicate. Already the first paragraph in the yellow box describes the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU @iNiravKotecha .. this fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `dateFormat` instead

```
df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"
```

Answer (score -1):

printing the date to console would give you the print2. It's printing the Date formats debug description. If you require a particular format you need to convert date into string with a DateFormatter. Check this [link](https://nsdateformatter.com/) you need more help to get the desired date format.

Comment: hey @Frankenstein that is not the problem .. the issue is that print 1 is showing March 12 2020 .. when it is converted back to "Date" it changes to December 22 2019!

Comment: Check the link given in the above answer if you have more doubt regarding how to create a date format.